# How to add syntax highlighting for kivy (.kv files) in VS 2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Python Tools for Visual Studio v2.2.2, Python 2.7 and kivy v1.9.1. It's the first time I am using kivy and python.

Running a sample kivy application works fine, but I miss the syntax completion/highlighting for .kv files.

I already searched for the problem, but with v1.9.1 kivy is integrated into an [existing python installation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist) and so the [former solutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20131115020945/http://www.ocularsoftware.com/2013/11/how-to-use-python-tools-for-visual-studio-to-develop-and-run-kivy-applications/) are obsolete as all the Paths are different now and I am not able to adapt the solution.

Adding another Python Enviroment for Kivy and refreshing the DB of the Interpreter didn't work.

I would appreciate if someone has a tip for me.

Comment: You can make Visual Studio use `.tmLanguage` syntax definition files, and you should be able to find one of those somewhere. I don’t know how you tell VS to use it without creating a VS extension though…